# Python zip magic for classes instead of tuples

Tags: python

Python [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function is
its own inverse (in a way), thus we can do this:

```
points = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]
xs, ys = zip(*points)
```

and now `xs=[1,3,5,7]` and `ys=[2,4,6,8]`.

I wonder if something similar can be done with [data class](https://docs.python.org/library/dataclasses.html) instances instead of tuples:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class XY:
    "2d point"
    x: float | int
    y: float | int

points = [XY(1,2), XY(3,4), XY(5,6), XY(7,8)]
xs, ys = zip(*[(p.x,p.y) for p in points])
```

but *without* an *explicit* list comprehension.

Of course, the result would not be a tuple `(xs,ys)` but a dict with keys `x`
and `y` because, without an explicit list comprehension, we would be collecting
*all* fields.

Comment: Note that an explicit comprehension is usually the best solution, as it's significantly faster and probably more readable.

Comment: @cup Seems like dataclasses were first introduced in Python 3.7 https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html "New in version 3.7."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With [`astuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple

@dataclass
class XY:
    "2d point"
    x: float | int
    y: float | int
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(astuple(self))

points = [XY(1,2), XY(3,4), XY(5,6), XY(7,8)]
xs, ys = zip(*points)
```

Or instead map it:

```
xs, ys = zip(*map(astuple, points))
```

Answer (score 37):

You can define custom `__iter__` magic function in your dataclass:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class XY:
    "2d point"
    x: float | int
    y: float | int

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

points = [XY(1,2), XY(3,4), XY(5,6), XY(7,8)]

xs, ys = zip(*points)
print(xs)
print(ys)
```

Prints:

```
(1, 3, 5, 7)
(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: This `__iter__` version is about 10 times as fast as the one which uses `astuple`. Great job.

Answer (score 10):

If you are looking for solutions which uses `zip`, others have answered already. However, if you are looking for the end results, which are `xs` and `ys` variables. You can just use list comprehension:

```py
xs = [point.x for point in points]
ys = [point.y for point in points]
```

This is simpler, easier to understand than other solutions which try to use zip.

## Update

In response to sds' comment: Yes, it takes two lines of code, but

1. Code is easy to read
2. It is simpler
3. It is much faster

To demonstrate the speed, I time my solution vs the `astuple` one:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple
import timeit


@dataclass
class XY:
    """2d point"""

    x: float | int
    y: float | int

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(astuple(self))


def my_method(points):
    xs = [point.x for point in points]
    ys = [point.y for point in points]
    return xs, ys


def astuple_method(points):
    xs, ys = zip(*points)
    return xs, ys


points = [XY(1, 2), XY(3, 4), XY(5, 6), XY(7, 8)]

# My time
my_time = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="my_method(points)",
    globals=globals(),
)
print(f"\n# my_method: {my_time}")

# astuple time
astuple_time = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="astuple_method(points)",
    globals=globals(),
)

print(f"# astuple_method: {astuple_time}")
print(f"# Ratio astuple:my: {astuple_time / my_time}")
```

Here is a sample output, which shows that my solution is about 20 times faster:

```
# my_method: 0.42180337477475405
# astuple_method: 8.835096125025302
# Ratio astuple:my: 20.9460062517122
```

Answer (score 8):

You get a hint if you try to do it with classes: `TypeError: 'XY' object is not iterable`.

Make the class iterable (add `__iter__`):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields


@dataclass()
class XY:
    "2d point"
    x: float | int
    y: float | int

    def __iter__(self):
        return (getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields(self))
```

Now:

```py
points = [XY(1, 2), XY(3, 4), XY(5, 6), XY(7, 8)]
xs, ys = zip(*points)

xs,ys # ((1, 3, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6, 8))
```

Answer (score 6):

An ugly solution, but one that doesn't require you to modify the existing class, is to provide a custom function that converts instances to an iterable, and then apply it with `map`.

For example:

```
def pt2iter(pt):
    yield pt.x
    yield pt.y

xs, ys = zip(*map(pt2iter, points))
```

The iterable can be anything. For example

```
def pt2iter(pt):
    return pt.x, pt.y
```

Answer (score 3):

Other than using `astuple`, you could make `XY` a `namedtuple` instead:

```
XY = namedtuple('XY', ['x', 'y'])
```

This is even the documented Example for a `nametuple` and brings the advantage of immutability (which seems logical for a point). And, of course, the iterability is given:

```
points = [XY(1,2), XY(3,4), XY(5,6), XY(7,8)]
xs, ys = zip(*points)
# (1, 3, 5, 7)
# (2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Or, building on top of another solution, you can create an iterable dataclass decorator:

```
def idataclass(**kwargs):     
    def deco(cls):
        cls = dataclass(cls, **kwargs)
        cls.__iter__  = lambda s: (getattr(s, field.name) for field  in fields(s))
        return cls
    return deco

 
@idataclass()
class XY:
    x: float | int
    y: float | int
```

Comment: How would the `**kwargs` be given?

Comment: @KellyBundy Adapted. Now, `@idataclass(**kwargs); class ...` will work

Comment: Am I doing it [wrong](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVHLTsMwEBRXf8Ue7cgU8a4iReoXcOLQCqHINHax6sTReiMaxJ9w6QU-iq_BiRtoffCuxzOjsffzu-3p1Tf7_VdH5nz-cxYM-hoqRWrtVAg6gK1bj_QPSTBWuyowVmkD9g_naxeKB99oCRcSsmz7pnATRA7DYsMWCVDAieCIOFFmZWlJY1lCJDtVv1QKQg58o0kRIZ8CzBpVawHGYzoD2OYQjQeR7FBTh83gytjiKKrHSmPxiJ0WbERgucpHxS4H47wi-Ih2NEL9KcRaH8vwkqflil_KKyGjml_Lm9TcyrvU3Mu5eGa7mLcf2O-25VnSCtZirDzdifT3hxFMo_gF)?

Comment: @KellyBundy You were doing what I was doing which was wrong of course. Basic parametrised decorators, changed now. Shouldn't use advanced idioms after midnight =)

Comment: Alright, now `@idataclass(order=True)` works, but `@idataclass` doesn't (although `@idataclass()` works).

Answer (score 3):

you can get a similar result with data class instances by using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [`var`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars) functions along with the `*` operator to unpack the fields of each instance. Instead of using a list comprehension, you can pass the instances directly to `zip` as separate arguments using the `*` operator:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class XY:
    "2d point"
    x: float or int
    y: float or int

points = [XY(1, 2), XY(3, 4), XY(5, 6), XY(7, 8)]
data_dict = dict(zip(('x', 'y'), zip(*(vars(p).values() for p in points))))

print(data_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'x': (1, 3, 5, 7), 'y': (2, 4, 6, 8)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **attrgetter** function from the operator module to extract the values of the *x* and *y* attributes from each instance of the **XY** class.

```
from operator import attrgetter
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class XY:
    "2d point"
    x: float | int
    y: float | int

points = [XY(1,2), XY(3,4), XY(5,6), XY(7,8)]
xs, ys = map(list, zip(*map(attrgetter('x', 'y'), points)))
```

The resulting tuples are then unpacked using the **zip(*...)** syntax and converted to lists using the **map(list, ...)** function.

for knowing more about attrgetter: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-operator-usage/